# Intellisense for Javascript in VSCode not working

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have been searching the web for a answer but cant find it. In vscode i cant get intellisense for javascript working.
Example:
var name = "test";
var name.to.... here i want it to suggest touppercase, but nothing is happening.

Any good suggestions about fixing this?

Comment: Works fine for me. Does VS Code know you're writing JavaScript?

Comment: Can you put a screenshot on imgur of a JS file in VS Code as well as posting your setttings JSON somewhere and then edit your question to include that? Could be helpful in figuring out the problem. Have you saved the file as a .js? Do you have any extensions installed that relate to javascript or typescript grammar?

Comment: It seems to be working if i do this:
var test = "test";
test.tolowercase; //Intellisense works here

But it does not work here
var test = promt("Name: ");
test.tol... No intellisense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the language selected is set to javaScript. when the file extension is `.js`  it's automatically set the lang to js. if your file does not have the  .js extension you just need to set it manually in the bottom bar.

[docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_language-id)

Answer (score 0):

Had a situation today, s1 has intellisense, but s2 has Not

adding '**let**' to s2 fixed the issue, maybe a scoped variable can help VS code infer the type & provide intellisense.

[image]